# How do you add Jeet and Rupture to Stylus-Brunch?

Tags: stylus, brunch, jeet-grid

I am trying to use Jeet and Rupture with my Stylus-Brunch.

What do I need to configure to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

It's incredibly simple, or at least was for me. I just added this to my `config.coffee` file:

```
plugins:
  stylus:
    plugins: ['rupture', 'jeet']
```

... and then ran `npm install -g rupture jeet` inside the brunch app folder (may need sudo)

Comment: At least with regards to jeet you want to be using -g (or --save-dev), not --save, as it's not a runtime dependancy. (I don't know anything about Rupture but it's likely the same if it's a Stylus plugin)

Comment: Make sure to edit your answer when you get the chance :)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to configure a new plugin — a fork of stylus-brunch with Jeet/Rupture.